# jQuery - Checking Check Box Values (Chaining jQuery functions Vs If Statment)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple check boxes and wanting to get an overall value for them all.

For example if one is checked then value is true/selected.

If none are checked then false/unchecked.

My HTML is:

```
<input id="one" type="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox">
<input id="four" type="checkbox">
<button onclick="check();">Is checked (jQuery Chained)</button>
<button onclick="check2();">Is checked(Big If Statement)</button>
```

My JavaScript/jQuery is:

```
function check() {
    var booleee = $('#one,#two,#three,#four').attr('checked');
    alert("Checked: " + booleee);
}

function check2() {
    if ($('#one').attr('checked') || $('#two').attr('checked') || $('#three').attr('checked') || $('#four').attr('checked')) {
        alert("Checked: true");
    }
    alert("Checked: false");
}
```

Js Fiddle: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XNBBR/)

Please note, I have solved this problem. This question is more to help me understand why my `checked2()` function works and my `check()` doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var booleee = $('#one,#two,#three,#four').attr('checked');` checks only whether the first (in this case `#one`) checkbox is checked.

From the [doc for attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

it should be

```
var booleee = $('#one,#two,#three,#four').filter(':checked').length > 0;
```

Also in new versions(>1.6) you need to use the property 'checked' (`.prop('checked')`) instead of `attr` in the alternative you have a [:checked filter](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) so `.is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not checking all the elements in the `selector`.

to make it work

```
  function check() {
    var booleee =$("input:checkbox:checked").length > 0;
    alert("Checked: " + booleee);
}
```

To more specific selection add form id in `selector`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XNBBR/3/)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach: http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/ZP78F/

```
function check() {
    var checks = $('input:checkbox');
    var checked = 0;
    checks.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checked = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (checked) {
        alert("Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Not checked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in html set checked property

```
<input id="one" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="two" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="three" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="four" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

you not defined checked so it show undefined  because it cant read this attribute and when you call second function then only false come in alert because their checkbox checked attribute not find

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/XNBBR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked = $(':checkbox:checked').length > 0;
```